# App crashes after adding onesignal ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework, onesignal

I got the error like below. I check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587224/android-cant-add-one-singnal/50587310#50587310) related to it. But how i solve this in ionic.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                      Process: io.ionic.starter, PID: 580
                      java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbq;
                          at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6487)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6082)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6022)
                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:211)
```

and the build.gradle generates like

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug"))
    releaseCompile(project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release"))
    compile "com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}
```

Comment: looks the same as the error on their github repo: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/298

Comment: @pleft but i don't have any dependencies related to firebase